# Embedded hovertool graph emulating Tableau

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hover, tableau-api, bokeh

I'm working on recreating a functionality that exists in Tableau for a dashboard I'm building in Python as our org doesn't have Tableau, but I haven't found anything on SO or in bokeh's documentation. Is there any way to recreate a embedded graph that's dynamically filtered in HoverTool in the same way [Tableau does here](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/11/viz-tooltip-here-78442)? ([Also shown in image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnLHU.png).)

A sample solution in d3 or js also works.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A tooltip made of a div is just that, a div, you can add anything to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43905388/5768908

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add chart to tooltip in d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904643/add-chart-to-tooltip-in-d3)

Comment: Check the Bokeh [Custom Tooltip](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html) where you can put an image in your tooltip. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481438/fixed-hovertool-tooltips-when-taping-an-element-of-a-bokeh-plot/55437025#55437025) is the same but the tooltip remains on the plot after clicking on the glyph. Also putting a graph into tooltip is possible in Bokeh but is a little bit more tricky (check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244088/bokeh-hovertools-which-run-arbitrary-python-code/55246644#55246644))

Comment: I would say this is probably possible, even perhaps with a real other Bokeh plot, especially with the recent `json_item` API, but AFAIK it has not been demonstrated. I will try to see if I can cobble an example together in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado, this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Ad of Bokeh 1.4, putting *live* "subplots" in tooltips is an area of active exploration with possibly some things that might work in the short term. However, the StackOverflow "answer" is that there is not yet a complete answer. Accordingly, I'd encourage you to join the discussion on the Project Discourse:

https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/bar-plot-inside-tooltip/4228

Since that venue is more suitable to open-ended discussion and iterative experiments.

If you only need *static images* of plots and can compute them ahead of time, you can certainly use Bokeh's `export_png` to generate the static images, which can then be put in a [custom tooltip](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip) the example there assumes the images are hosted somehwhere but you could also put base64 image data in the column data source instead of links.